# Extend from class built by a loop within the same loop

Tags: css, less

I am using a loop to generate a fair amount of background gradients with a different color each. I'm also extending some general styles from a dummy class.

```
.update-bg-essentials{
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

@bg-types: blogpost,ppic,nvideo,pvideo,album,user,comment;
@bg-colors: @pink,@pink-dark,#5c9c80,#6c779e,#826097,#3dac98,#af9d53;

.generate-bgs(@i: length(@bg-types)) when (@i > 0) {
    @bg-name: extract(@bg-types, @i);
    @bg-color: extract(@bg-colors, @i);

    .evt_bg_@{bg-name} {
        &:extend(.update-bg-essentials);
        border-color: @bg-color;
        background: @grey;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%, @bg-color 150%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,@grey), color-stop(150%,@bg-color));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{grey}', endColorstr='@{bg-color}',GradientType=1 );
        .update_head {
            background: @bg-color;
        }
    }
    .generate-bgs((@i - 1));
}
.generate-bgs;
```

The output looks like this:

```
.update-bg-essentials,
.evt_bg_comment,

...

.evt_bg_blogpost {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
.evt_bg_comment {
  border-color: #af9d53;
  background: #c6c7c9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #af9d53 150%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #c6c7c9), color-stop(150%, #af9d53));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #af9d53 150%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #af9d53 150%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #af9d53 150%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #af9d53 150%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c6c7c9', endColorstr='#af9d53', GradientType=1);
}
.evt_bg_comment .update_head {
  background: #af9d53;
}

...

.evt_bg_blogpost {
  border-color: #e1409e;
  background: #c6c7c9;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #e1409e 150%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, #c6c7c9), color-stop(150%, #e1409e));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #e1409e 150%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #e1409e 150%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #e1409e 150%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #c6c7c9 0%, #e1409e 150%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#c6c7c9', endColorstr='#e1409e', GradientType=1);
}
.evt_bg_blogpost .update_head {
  background: #e1409e;
}
```

This works but it annoys me to have that dummy class in my less code only for the generated classes to extend from.
So I tried this instead.

```
@bg-types: blogpost,ppic,nvideo,pvideo,album,user,comment;
@bg-colors: @pink,@pink-dark,#5c9c80,#6c779e,#826097,#3dac98,#af9d53;

.generate-bgs(@i: length(@bg-types)) when (@i > 0) {
    @bg-name: extract(@bg-types, @i);
    @bg-color: extract(@bg-colors, @i);

    .evt_bg_@{bg-name} {
        & when (@i = length(@bg-types)) {
            margin: 3px;
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 8px;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            position: relative;
            padding: 0;
        }
        & when (@i < length(@bg-types)){
            @extender: extract(@bg-types, length(@bg-types));
            &:extend(.evt_bg_@{extender});
        }
        border-color: @bg-color;
        background: @grey;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%, @bg-color 150%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,@grey), color-stop(150%,@bg-color));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg,  @grey 0%,@bg-color 150%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='@{grey}', endColorstr='@{bg-color}',GradientType=1 );
        .update_head {
            background: @bg-color;
        }
    }
    .generate-bgs((@i - 1));
}
.generate-bgs;
```

My approach is to generate the first background with the styles from the dummy class and let the others extend from it. But unfortunately this doesn't work. The extend gets ignored both with the generated class and with it coded in.

Is this because it is not actually there yet?

How can I get this to work without using a dummy class?

Comment: No, currently extend does not support any variables as arguments (neither interpolated i.e. [#2200](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2200) nor a DR). Your use-case will eventually be supported via something like [#1177](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1177), but so far none was interested enough to actually implement it.

Comment: @seven-phases-max What a shame. I hope this gets added soon. The ability to extend from mixins would be IMO a powerful addition.

Comment: Well, look at it at different angle, how many classes my CSS aready have? 10? 100? 1K? more? why would I care of just one more? ;)

Comment: Yeah I know. But in cases like this I get the irrational urge to do things as clean as possible ;D